# Removing cv-qualifier from templated vector function

Tags: c++, g++

I'm writing some code that randomly picks an element from a given vector with any generic type. I've successfully made a function that returns a copy of a random element, but it'd be convenient for me if there's a similar function that returns the *iterator* of that element instead. This is what I have, in which the random iterator is yielded from adding a random number to the begin iterator through a generator function:

```
template <class T>
typename std::vector<T>::iterator pickElementIterator(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    if (v.empty())
    {
        // error
        return v.end();
    }

    return v.begin() + generate(v.size());
}
```

This compiles successfully if no code uses it. But as soon as I try to substitute in some vector with type Foo, the following error comes up using g++:

> could not convert '(& v)->std::vector::end()' from '__normal_iterator<const Foo*,[...]>' to
> __normal_iterator<Foo*,[...]>'

For both returns. It seems it adds a const to the type when attempting to convert it for returning. I've tried std::decay on both returns but it does not accept those arguments. That's as far as my knowledge on template programming goes, and not much about this is found anywhere I looked.

**Note:** "typename" is in the return type because otherwise g++ complains with:

> need 'typename' before 'std::vector<_RealType>::iterator' because 'std::vector<_RealType>' is a dependent scope
> Which is still not clear for me.

Comment: Since `v` is `const`, `v.begin() + some_int` produces a `vector::const_iterator`, not `vector::iterator`. And so does `v.end()`. Change your function's return type accordingly.

Comment: Please make a [mre]. Just a couple of lines that calls this function is enough.

Comment: return a ```const_iterator``` or simply return ```auto```

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<T>::begin()`/`std::vector<T>::end()` return a `const_iterator` when `const` qualified, not an `iterator` (which is mutable).

The reason this fails to compile is because `const_iterator`s cannot be converted to mutable `iterator` types. The fix is simple: change the return type to be `const_iterator`:

```cpp
template <class T>
typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator pickElementIterator(const std::vector<T>& v)
//                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If you're in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) or above, you can also just use `auto` without a declared return type so that it can deduce it itself, e.g.:

```cpp
template <class T>
auto pickElementIterator(const std::vector<T>& v)
```

---

**Note:** The reason you observed that this compiled successfully when not used is because templates can't fully be evaluated until instantiated. The compiler has to assume that anything that relies on a template parameter (for example, type `T`) might produce a valid instantiation thanks to template specialization.

For example, the compiler must assume that there *may* exist a `T` such that `const std::vector<T>::begin()` returns something which could construct a `std::vector<T>::iterator`. This could happen if `vector<T>` were specialized.

As a result, you won't often see many diagnostics outside of syntax errors until you're actually instantiating a template

Comment: Thanks for the insight, the main issue I wasn't understanding was whether the deduced T type was wrong or the return type. Now I understand it's the type returned by end() and begin(). auto definitely helps in these situations indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you let `auto` decide what kind of iterator that is returned. If you use C++11 you can use a trailing return type like `decltype(v.begin())` and in C++14 and later, that's not needed.

If you also make use of template template parameters, you don't have to make it work for `vector`s only. `v.begin() + generate(v.size())` requires random access though, so I suggest using [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to get the resulting iterator.

Example:

```
#include <iterator> // std::next

template <template <class, class...> class C, class T, class... Args>
auto pickElementIterator(const C<T, Args...>& c) -> decltype(c.begin()) {
    if(c.empty()) return c.end();
    return std::next(c.begin(), generate(c.size()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the time being it won't need to be that generic, but I will definitely keep that in mind in case I want to expand the types of containers to use. The std::next optimisation was also something I was unaware of, very subtle, but I think I understand it.